# .NET: Getting the en-HK culture (or any custom culture) on Azure App Service

Tags: .net, azure, cultureinfo, culture, azure-web-app-service

I have a web application currently running in Azure Cloud Services (web role) on the [latest Guest OS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-guestos-update-matrix/). On this guest OS, the culture en-HK is available. The cultures available on this Guest OS seem to be similar to those available on my Windows 10 developer machine (400+ cultures, reflecting Microsoft's move to the Unicode CLDR-style culture support). That is, this OS seems to be "up to date" with respect to cultures.

I have another web application deployed as a web app running in Azure App Service. There, the en-HK culture is *not* available, and a dump of all available cultures shows that only around 200 cultures are available (roughly the ones I used to see on my old Windows 8 developer machine). That is, the OS in which the web app in the Azure App Service is running seems "outdated" with respect to culture availability.

I can run code with administrator privileges in the Cloud Service, but I *cannot do so* in the App Service, so I can't register a custom culture either (even with hacks like [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404375%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

So far I haven't been able to find any documentation about what kind of operating system Azure App Service runs on, and what the update process there is.

**My question(s):** is there any way to find out if and when the newer cultures like en-HK will be available for .NET code running in Azure App Service? Or am I missing some configuration option for App Service that lets me choose a more "up to date" OS with "fresher" cultures (I've already selected .NET 4.6, but I don't think that has much to do with it)? It doesn't have anything to do with the pricing tier, does it?

Comment: Do you have found a solution for this problem? I have the same, now.

Comment: Yes, we ended up using IKVM.NET to call the Java ICU library (Internationalization Components for Unicode) on the server, which used the same CLDR data as Globalize on the client. Now, having moved over to Asp.Net Core 2.0 (and IKVM no longer supported/maintained), we're using Globalize.js through NodeServices/JavascriptServices, which solves the problem nicely and makes sure we have consistent internationalization on both the client and server. Hope that helps!